# Desktop take 10-15 seconds to turn on after pressing the power button

Tags: boot, power-supply, desktop-computer

Just after assembling my brand new PC,  i am having a delay of 10-15 seconds in booting after i press the power button on my Desktop.
For 10-15 seconds nothing happens but after that the fans , motherboard and GPU starts up.
And then after 2-3 seconds the monitor starts displaying.

My configuration:

- [AMD Ryzen 7 3700x](https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/amd-ryzen-7-3700x)
- [ASUS TUF B550 Plus motherboard](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/TUF-GAMING-B550-PLUS/)
- [ASUS RTX 2070 Super (Nvidia GeForce RTX 2070 SUPER)](https://www.asus.com/us/Graphics-Cards/ROG-STRIX-RTX2070S-O8G-GAMING/)
- 8GB x 2 DDR4 RAM
- 2 TB 5400 RPM hard drive
- 120 GB SSD
- [Gigabyte B700H PSU (700W)](https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Power-Supply/B700H/sp#sp)

Power supply calculator is showing 400 watts.

Also there is one thing that my PSU to wall cable has only 2 pins. Can this be an issue?

(Sorry for bad english)

Comment: Newegg's PSU calculator agrees with your 400W & since you have a 700W PSU I don't think thats the issue. 1-While your CPU doesn't have integrated graphics I'm curious if removing graphics card causes quicker start? 2-Assume you have secured the graphics card & connected power to it?

Comment: Basic question: does the PC eventually turn on & work fine after that delay? Or are you getting beeps or error codes?

Comment: The documentation for the BIOS settings for that M/B seems to be sparse. If you go into the "Advanced" mode, is there a section named "Boot" and does it have a setting for "CSM (Compatibility Settings Module)"? You could try setting that to "Disabled".

Comment: For the avoidance of doubt, that CSM is not the same as the "Corporate Stable Model" CSM. A bit of a failure on Asus's part for keeping the TLAs clear.

Answer (score 0):

1. I'd verify the power button (front panel) cables are plugged in correctly
2. I'd try to do a BIOS update: asus.com/Motherboards/TUF-GAMING-B550-PLUS/HelpDesk_BIOS
3. I wouldn't think the PSU cable to wall outlet being 2 pins would cause this, but it's probably a good idea for it to have a ground pin. If you have another cable wouldn't hurt to try
4. I'd call ASUS lastly
5. If you're savvy/comfortable you could try to short the power pins on the motherboard with a paper clip or better yet a jump clip (found on motherboards or older hard drives):
   [image: Motherboard diagram]
   [image: Zoomed in motherboard diagram]

Here are some links from ASUS's site for your motherboard:
[Troubleshooting - No Power/No Boot/No Display](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1042632)
[ASUS Q-LED troubleshooting for no power on/no boot/no display](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1042678)

Comment: No. https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1040820

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the delay.

I have checked all the tips given by you and andrew. Here are the results:

1) Updated BIOS
 
2) CSM was already disabled in BIOS

3) Removed the graphics card but still the took 10-15 seconds to power up the fans , gpu etc
4) Checked the front panel cables
5) Cleared CMOS.

None of the above helped .

Comment: I found a interesting thing though. I am currently using a multiplug to connect the monitor , CPU , mobile charger , printer.
Whenever i powered the desktop  with only CPU and monitor plugs cabled , it booted fast in 1-2 seconds. What could this mean?

Comment: I assume you mean a power stripe (multiple outlet plugs going to one wall outlet)? I'm thinking your printer is drawing alot of power & maybe causing the PC to not get enough causing the delay. Do you have another power strip to try? Maybe it's the electrical wall outlet, could try another one? Process of elimination :) It is seeming turning into an electrical issue & there is  a stack exchange site for that

Comment: Hi gregg. Yes i mean the power stripe and  thanks for the suggestions. I will try those.
Also please can you give the name for the electrical issue site.

Comment: Make sure you upvote answers or comments that were helpful as that is how people get points/credit on these sites. Here are two sites that may help: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Hi Gregg, unable to upvote as I don't have 15 reputation